# Paging ListBox with ReactiveUI and Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, reactiveui, caliburn.micro.reactiveui

I'm trying to implement a paging mechanism for a listbox using Caliburn.Micro.ReactiveUI with a call to EF using ".Skip(currentPage).Take(pageSize)". I'm new to ReactiveUI and Reactive in general. I'm sure this is supposed to be easy.

I've got a single "SearchParameters" class which I needs to be observed and the search function needs to execute when any of the properties on the SearchParameters object changes.

You can see from the commented-out code that I've tried to define the class as a ReactiveObject as well. The current implementation though is with CM's PropertyChangedBase. The individual properties are bound textboxes in my view using CM's conventions:

```
public class SearchParameters : PropertyChangedBase
    {

        private string _searchTerm;
        public string SearchTerm
        {
            get { return _searchTerm; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _searchTerm) return;
                _searchTerm = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SearchTerm);

            }
        }
        private int _pageSize;
        public int PageSize
        {
            get { return _pageSize; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _pageSize) return;
                _pageSize = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PageSize);

            }
        }

        private int _skipCount;
        public int SkipCount
        {
            get { return _skipCount; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _skipCount) return;
                _skipCount = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SkipCount);

            }
        }

        //private string _searchTerm;
        //public string SearchTerm
        //{
        //    get { return _searchTerm; }
        //    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _searchTerm, value); }
        //}
        //private int _pageSize;
        //public int PageSize
        //{
        //    get { return _pageSize; }
        //    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _pageSize, value); }
        //}

        //private int _skipCount;
        //public int SkipCount
        //{
        //    get { return _skipCount; }
        //    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _skipCount, value); }
        //}

    }
```

"SearchService" has the following method which needs to execute when any one of SearchParameter's values change:

```
public async Task<SearchResult> SearchAsync(SearchParameters searchParameters)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var query = (from m in _hrEntities.Departments select m);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchParameters.SearchTerm))
            {
                searchParameters.SearchTerm = searchParameters.SearchTerm.Trim();
                query = query.Where(
                    x => x.Employee.LastName.Contains(searchParameters.SearchTerm) || x.Employee.FirstName.Contains(searchParameters.SearchTerm)).Skip(searchParameters.SkipCount).Take(searchParameters.PageSize);
            }
            return new SearchResult
            {
                SearchTerm = searchParameters.SearchTerm,
                Matches = new BindableCollection<DepartmentViewModel>(query.Select(x => new DepartmentViewModel{ Department = x }).Skip(searchParameters.SkipCount).Take(searchParameters.PageSize))
            };
        });
    }
```

Here's how I've tried to wire all of this up in MainViewModel's ctor and where Rx gets hazy for me:

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveScreen
{
private SearchParameters _searchParameters;
        public SearchParameters SearchParameters
        {
            get { return _searchParameters; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _searchParameters) return;
                _searchParameters = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SearchParameters);
            }
        }
{

public void MainViewModel()
{
    var searchService = new SearchService();
    //default Skip and PageSize values
    SearchParameters = new Services.SearchParameters { SkipCount = 0 , PageSize = 10};

    var searchParameters = this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.SearchParameters)
                .Value()
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.3));
    var searchResults = searchParameters.SelectMany(parameters => searchService.SearchAsync(parameters));
            var latestMatches = searchParameters
               .CombineLatest(searchResults,    
                   (searchParameter, searchResult) =>
                       searchResult.SearchTerm != searchParameter.SearchTerm
                           ? null
                           : searchResult.Matches)
               .Where(matches => matches != null);
    _departmentViewModels = latestMatches.ToProperty(this, x => x.DepartmentViewModels);
            searchParameters.Subscribe(x => Debug.WriteLine(x));
}
}
```

In the above example the call to SearchAsync doesn't execute. It seems that changes to SearchParameter's properties aren't being observed.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing this although I'd be interested in hearing other solutions if anyone has suggestions. I'm not sure if this is the best way but it works:

First, I defined a computed property in my SearchParameters class that returns a string and reevaluates anytime CurrentPage, SkipCount and PageSize are updated from the View:

```
public string ParameterString
        {
            get { return String.Format("SearchTerm={0}|SkipCount={1}|PageSize={2}", SearchTerm, SkipCount, PageSize); }
        }
```

Next, in my MainViewModel ctor I simply observe the computed rather than attempting to react to SearchTerm, SkipCount and PageSize individually (which my original question was asking how to do):

```
var searchTerms = this
                .ObservableForProperty(x => x.SearchParameters.ParameterString)
                .Value()
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.3));

var searchResults = searchTerms.SelectMany(parameters => SearchService.SearchAsync(parameters));
            var latestMatches = searchTerms
               .CombineLatest(searchResults,
                   (searchTerm, searchResult) =>
                       searchResult.SearchTerm != searchTerm
                           ? null
                           : searchResult.Matches)
               .Where(matches => matches != null);
```

Finally, in my SearchService I parse the parameter string to get the current values:

```
var parameters = searchParameters.Split('|');
            var searchTerm = "";
            var skipCount = 0;
            var pageSize = 0;
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                if (parameter.Contains("SearchTerm="))
                {searchTerm = parameter.Replace("SearchTerm=", "");}
                else if (parameter.Contains("SkipCount="))
                { skipCount = Convert.ToInt32(parameter.Replace("SkipCount=", "")); }
                else if (parameter.Contains("PageSize="))
                { pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(parameter.Replace("PageSize=", "")); }
            }
```